# How do I return the nth dataset title from a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am working on a python project in which I would like to return the title of the nth dataset in a database. The user should be able to input a number, say 4, and the code will output the title of the 4th dataset. I tried using a for loop, but my code just returns the first dataset 4 times instead of the 4th dataset. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response=requests.get('http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=&sort=metadata_created+desc')

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

num=input("Enter a number:")
print(num)
data=[]

for x in range(int(num)+1):
    title=soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'notes'})
    dataSet=title.text
    data.append(dataSet)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `find_all` method to get all the titles. Then you can get the `num` element of the titles:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response=requests.get('http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=&sort=metadata_created+desc')

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

num=input("Enter a number:")
print(num)
data=[]

titles = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'notes'})

title=titles[int(num)-1]
dataSet=title.text
data.append(dataSet)

print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!